# Update Based on rowid in Oracle

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to update a table value using join in oracle(11g),
I have used rowid as join parameter for same table, Is it safe to use rowid as a join parameter.
Following is the query which i am using for updation, I have tested the same on local database it is working fine, but is there any scenario that there may be rowid mis-match?

```
MERGE 
INTO    GEOTAG g 
USING   (SELECT  g2.rowid AS rid, um.RETAILER_CODE
FROM    GEOTAG g2 
JOIN    RETAILER_AD_DSE b 
ON      b.CODE = g2.RETAILER_CODE
JOIN USER_HIERARCHY_MASTER um
ON um.RETAILER_PRIMARY_ETOPUP = b.RETAILER_PRIMARY_ETOPUP) src 
ON      (g.rowid = src.rid) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET g.RETAILER_CODE = src.RETAILER_CODE;
```

Comment: Are you sure this sql is semanticaly correct?  It selects rows with `geotag.retailer_code=retailer_ad_dse.code` and updates the same column?

Comment: thanks frank i have updated the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `rowid` will be unique in a table so if by "safe" you just mean that you'll be joining a row to itself then, yes, this is safe.

On the other hand, your code seems to be a rather overly complicated way to do a correlated update.  I suspect you just want this (you can omit the `WHERE EXISTS` if the there will always be a matching row in `retailer_ad_dse` and `user_hierarchy_master`).

```
UPDATE geotag g
   SET g.retailer_code = (SELECT code
                            FROM retailer_ad_dse rad
                                 JOIN user_hierarchy_master uhm
                                   ON uhm.retailer_primary_etopup = rad.retailer_primary_etopup
                           WHERE g.retailer_code = rad.code)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT code
                 FROM retailer_ad_dse rad
                      JOIN user_hierarchy_master uhm
                        ON uhm.retailer_primary_etopup = rad.retailer_primary_etopup
                 WHERE g.retailer_code = rad.code)
```

Comment: Hi Justin thanks for answering, I had used the query (where exists) for updating 70k records but it took too long to execute so i changed it to merge based on rowid.

Comment: @ShaileshYadav - I am a bit hard-pressed to imagine why the query plan would be meaningfully different.  If you don't want to investigate why the optimizer is picking a poor plan (presumably) for the standard approach, you certainly can use an odd `merge` construct instead (though I'd really want to use the primary key rather than the `rowid` in the join).  I'd make sure to leave a bunch of comments for the next person, though.

Comment: @JustinCave - I didn't read the OP's attempted MERGE in detail, but "joining" (really, matching in a MERGE statement) on ROWID makes sense when you want to update the PK. You can match by PK, but then you can't update it in the same MERGE statement. The ROWID trick is pretty standard, albeit not intellectually pleasing; I have seen it used several times exactly for this reason.

Comment: @mathguy - If `retailer_code` is the primary key of `geotag` then, sure, matching on the `rowid` makes sense.  Just from the identifiers, though, it seems unlikely.  And it sounds like the issue with the standard correlated update was performance not an Oracle error.